# Rewriting arcgis script using GRASS

Tags: gis

I would like to look at rewriting an arcgis python script that consists of alot of raster manipulation, so it can be used in qgis. I am new to this and not sure how feasible this is. The following are the methods in the arcgis script:

```
gp = arcgisscripting.create()
gp.OverwriteOutput 
gp.AddWarning
gp.AddMessage
gp.CopyRaster
gp.AddField
gp.CalculateField
gp.extent
gp.PointToRaster
gp.EucDirection
gp.Times
gp.Divide
gp.Minus
gp.SingleOutputMapAlgebra
gp.CreateConstantRaster
gp.Plus
gp.Sample
gp.CellSize
gp.ZonalStatistics
gp.Buffer
gp.PathDistance
gp.Describe
gp.tableselect
gp.ReclassByTable
gp.Reclassify
gp.FocalStatistics
gp.Basin
gp.FlowDirection
```

Is this possible using python and GRASS?  It would appear that this might be more successful than attempting to use GDAL. I wanted to get some expert advice and opinion before spending the time.

Answer (score 1):

Without a more specific question it's difficult to say, but maybe take a look at these functions:

- v.to.rast
- r.buffer / v.buffer
- [r.watershed](http://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/grass/gdp/html_grass63/r.watershed.html)
- [r.stream.*](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R.stream.*)

For GIS specific questions you may find it helpful to ask at [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Just for those reading this some years later(like me): as of GRASS GIS 7, there is a new Python library available, see http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/libpython/